# Usage of “ist gewesen” vs “ist gegangen” in a conversation

Tags: verb-usage

Reading a Star Wars novel, there is a dialog between Senator Padme and Anikin Skywalker in her apartment:

> Padme – Würdest du bitte Kaf machen, Liebling? Ich mache mich in der
>   Zeit fertig.

Anikin goes to the kitchen, but gets lost in his thoughts.   Padme then raises her voice from outside the kitchen:

> Padme -   Ani, bist du etwa auf Charra gewesen, um den Kaf selbst
>   anzubauen?

Since Anikin has not yet prepared the Kaf, I would have said “Ani, bist du etwa nach Charra gegangen, um….”.  Can someone explain why “ist gewesen” works in this context?

Source:  STAR WARS – Clone Wars:  Keine Gefangenen, Karen Traviss, blanvalet 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically both sentences work fine, but they have different meanings.

"Bist du etwa nach Charra gegangen" implies something like "Why did you go to Place A and not some other Place B?". e.g. "Warum bist du zu McDonalds gegangen und nicht zu Burger King um meinen Kaf zu holen?"

But Padme wants to ask Anakin what took him so long to get her some "Kaf", like "Hey, where have you been? What took you so long?"

"Where have you been" translates to "Wo bist du gewesen?" and Padme uses it in an ironic way "What took you so long? Have you been to Charra (a place far far away) to make my kaf?"

If Anakin already made the Kaf or not doesn't matter, as all Padme knows she didn't received her Kaf yet.

This kind of ironic use of "Wo bist du gewesen, in ... ?" is common in german language, when someone is late or needs a lot of time to accomplish a given task.

Comment: _"Warum bist du nach McDonalds gegangen und nicht nach Burger King um meinen Kaf zu holen?"_ Hier macht **nach** keinen Sinn.

Comment: Ok, stimmt. **Nach** ist die falsche Präposition. Zur Strafe lese ich 5 mal [diesen Zwiebelfischartikel](http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/schule/zwiebelfibel-ich-geh-nach-aldi-a-398751.html) ;)

Answer (score 0):

*Charra* is a planet and this is the reason why "*bist du auf Charra gewesen*" works in this context.

In german you usually don't say "*nach einem Planeten gehen*" or "*nach einem Planeten sein*" but instead "*auf einem Planeten sein*".

In the event that *Charra* would have been a city or specific region where they plant caf your version would work, like in "Bist du etwa nach London gegangen [...]"

Comment: _"Charra is a planet and this is the reason why ..."_ That's wrong. Also the use of ***nach*** is not in question here.

Comment: Die Abwertung dieser korrekten Antwort verstehe ich nicht. Darüber hinaus geht es sehr wohl um **nach**; schließlich ist es das, was der OP gesagt hätte: “nach Charra gefangen“.

Comment: @Björn Dann war mein Rat an den OP seinen ursprünglichen Beispielsatz [zu ändern](https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/43406/2) vielleicht keine so gute Idee?

Comment: Oh, in der App sehe ich nicht, dass etwas geändert wurde.

Comment: Zum Zeitpunkt als ich die Antwort geschrieben habe, standen diese beiden Varianten zur Diskussion: "bist du etwa auf Charra gewesen" und "bist du etwa nach Charra gegangen". Dass die Frage geändert wurde sehe ich zwar, aber nicht, dass dem OP dazu geraten wurde (z.b. in den Kommentaren). Und da Charra definitiv ein eigener Planet und keine Stadt/Region ist, bleibe ich momentan auch bei meiner Antwort, denn genau das macht für mich den Unterschied in der Formulierung aus.

Comment: @tallistroan _"denn genau das macht für mich den Unterschied in der Formulierung aus."_ Nein, der Unterschied ist, das _sein_ und _gehen_ verschiedene Verben sind. Mit _nach_ (oder anderen Präpositionen wie _zu_, o.ä.) hat es nichts zu tun.